# How do you write a proper Viewswitcher in web forms and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an asp.net website using web forms. I also have an asp.net/jquery mobile site that is a mobile version of my main site. I want to write a viewswitcher that will switch to the jquery mibile site on mobile and gives the option to go to desktop.

How do I write the Viewswitcher.ascx and Viewswitcher.ascx.vb pages?

Similar to [this link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx), but a bit different and not with mvc.

Comment: Haha nobody knows the Answer?  Wow... stack lost some street cred with this one.

Comment: This one has been driving me up the wall as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do some research on HTML5 responsive design to attain the desired result.

Comment: I don't think you know what I'm talking about. I am very aware of responsive design.

Comment: That's good, Michael, then you are aware that two separate sites (desktop and mobile) with a view switcher is a very old design technique and has since been replaced by HTML5 / CSS3 responsive design.